# How to share EntityManagerFactory Object across the various Resource files in a Restlet application?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, restlet

I would like to create one EMF object and use it in various Resource class objects.. any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is to use a class which follows the singleton design pattern - for more details see - http://vatsalad.wordpress.com/2010/03/05/single-entitymanagerfactory-object-across-various-restlet-resources/